# I can't make logs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, log, file-permissions

I'm trying to log information using an `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` instance, but for some reason `var/log/system.log` file doesn't exist and Magento can't create it; and when I create manually that file then the Magento is able to write my logs in that file and I think I don't have to create manually my logs files it doesn't make sense.

The file directories have the correct permissions and I have my Magento instance in developer mode.

I don't know if anybody can help me with this problem.

This is my code:

```
class Cron
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function logHello()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Hello from Cron job!');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this blog](http://magento.com/blog/technical/logging-approach-magento-2)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a log file 'mylog.log' inside var/log/ and p
lace this code inside your function

```
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Here your cmment");
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested **Steve Johnson** reference is correct.

Otherwise simply copy paste the below line of code it will create **mylog.txt** file in your `Magento` root folder.

```
file_put_contents('mylog.txt', print_r("\n" . $result_data,true), FILE_APPEND);
```